Factoring differential equation with variable coefficients
We have the differential equation
$$F(D)y=0$$ where $F(D)=xD^2-(x^2+2)D+x$.
The official solution factorizes $F(D)$ as $(xD-2)(D-x)$ and then argues by expanding y with this factorized form that this indeed yields the original expression $F(D)y$. But the idea of factoring like this seems out of the blue. If we try to think of $D$ as a variable rather than an operator we could get close to the actual facorization as $xD(D-x)-(D-x)-D$ but that also doesn't work and of course we can't treat $D$ as a variable like this. But it seems to give a clue about at least one factor even though the calculation isn't valid. So won't there be a systemic way to find the factorization? Or will it be always out of nowhere kind idea?It will be really helpful if someone sheds light on this.

The idea is that $F(D)$ is a quadratic map of $D$ and that you try to solve it using $D$ as a variable and $x$ a kind of constant.

As said by mathcounterexamples.net in his comment $-$ and by myself in my answer to your previous post by the way $-$, $F(D)$ is a quadratic map in $D$, so that it can be factored  in the same way as a second-degree polynomial, i.e. $F(D) = a(D-r)(D-s)$, where $a$, $r$ ans $s$ are functions of $x$. Then, apply this operator to $y$, compare the coefficients with the original expression for $F(D)$ and solve the obtained differential equations for the parameters $a,r,s$.

@Abezhiko could you please write a detailed solution? In your previous answer I could not understand how you determined the coefficients since there were more variables than equations. It will be very helpful of you to post a solution in this example.

@a_i_r. Gonçalo preempted me with a slightly different (but more suitable to the present case) parametrization.

@Abezhiko I actually wanted to know how the simultaneous systems of equations can be solved without inspections(trial and errors) as it can be quite hard to determine the unknowns if the equations were more complex. Also why can we assume there has to a factor of the form $(xD-f(x))$,in particular $x$ before $D$? Shouldn't we assume $a(D-f(x))(D-g(x))$?

@a_i_r. It is not about assumption, but convenient reparametrization. Gonçalo distributed my $a$ factor $-$ which is known to be $a(x) = x$ (because it will correspond to the coefficient of $D^2$) $-$, before renaming/rescaling the first parameter as $f := ar$. Unfortunately, the system of equations for the said parameters will always end up with a Riccati equation in the case of a second-order differential operator, whose solution is often easier to be guessed by inspection/trial than solved formally. Practice will help you to develop intuition about suitable parametrizations/factorizations).

Let $F(D)=(xD-f(x))(D-g(x))$. Applying $F(D)$ to $y$, we get
\begin{align}
F(D)y&=xy''-xgy'-xg'y-fy'+fgy \\
&=[xD^2-(xg+f)D-xg'+fg]\,y. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Comparing $(1)$ with $F(D)=xD^2-(x^2+2)D+x$, we conclude that $f$ and $g$ must satisfy the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
xg+f=x^2+2, \\
fg-xg'=x.
\end{cases} \tag{2}
$$
By inspection, we find that a solution to $(2)$ is $f(x)=2, g(x)=x$, hence
$$
F(D)=(xD-2)(D-x). \tag{3}
$$

Thank you for answering but I do not understand a few things. Why did you assume $F(D)$ is of the form $(xD-f(x))(D-g(x))$? Essentially why $x$ before $D$ in the first factor? Also in the equation 2,you determined $f$ and $g$ by inspection. But isn't there any systematic way of figuring those out apart from guesses?I mean if $F(D)$ were more complex,we couldn't have got $f$ and $g$ so easily by trial and error. Thank you for bearing with me.

(i) Because it has the form of the "official solution"; I also could have assumed $F(D)=a(D-f)(D-g)$, but this is equivalent to $(aD-\tilde{f})(D-g)$, where $\tilde{f}=af$, and an easy calculation would show that $a=x$; or I could have assumed $F(D)=(D-f)(xD-g)$, and this is equal to $xD^2-(x^2+2)D+x$ if $f(x)=\frac{3}{x}$ and $g(x)=x^2$ (to be continued).

(ii) Solving the first equation of $(2)$ for $f$ and substituting the result in the second equation, one obtains the non-linear Riccati equation $g'=-g^2+\left(x+\frac{2}{x}\right)g-1$. With the substitution $g=\frac{u'}{u}$, it is transformed into the linear ODE $xu''-(x^2+2)u'+u=0$... The moral of the story is that there is a systematic way of determining $f$ and $g$, but it is as complicated as solving the original problem. As remarked by Abezhiko, it is often simpler to guess $f$ and $g$.
